# SQL select distinct where exist row for each id in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table A and B with a relationship: A n<->1 B relationship.

They are joined over field A.b = B.id, where B.id is unique

I have a parameter which is a bunch of ids of B.

I want to get distinct A.id that have *all* given B.ids assigned.

***Example:***

**Table B**

```
| id | ...
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
```

**Table A**

```
| id |  b  | ...
| 1  |  1  |
| 1  |  2  |
| 1  |  3  |
| 2  |  1  |
| 2  |  2  |
               <-- id=2 is not assigned to b=3 !
| 3  |  1  |
| 3  |  2  |
| 3  |  3  |
```

**Expected result for parameter B.ids="1,2,3"**: 1, 3 (2 misses the required B.id=3)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select id
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on a.b = b.id
group by id
having count(distinct b) = (select count(distinct b) from tableB);
```

Note that this can possibly be simplified with some assumptions.  For instance, if you know the `b` ids are unique, then you don't need the `count(distinct)` (`count()` is then sufficient.)

EDIT:

If you want a list of ids that you want to check, you can use:

```
select id
from tableA a
where find_in_set(a.b, IDLISTHERE) > 0
group by id
having count(distinct b) = (select count(distinct b) from tableB where find_in_set(a.b, IDLISTHERE) > 0);
```

Comment: for param= "1,2,3": maybe add: "having count(b) = :param_size
    where b.id IN (:param)"

Answer (score 1):

```
select id  from tableA a join tableB b  on a.b = b.id
group by id
having count(distinct b) = (select count(distinct b) from tableB);
```

Comment: That is what Gordon Linoff posted already, but where is the parameter? I only want those from table A which are assigned to selection of Bs as defined by a parameter.